# E-Mail Piping With Exchange Server?

Tags: exchange-server

I am using Exchange 2007 and would like to pipe e-mails that hit a certain mailbox to a PHP script.  Everything I read so far suggests creating an separate e-mail account on a different domain (POP3 or IMAP) and forwarding my Exchange e-mails onto the other account.  Then to use cPanel to pipe it to a PHP script.

Is there a native feature in Exchange for me to pipe e-mails so I don't have to set up an additional server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't do it with Exchange 2007, it's not an option in Exchange 2007.